# matlab-reading large comma delimited files where each field is enclosed with ""

Tags: regex, matlab, csv, import, scanf

I would like to import data into Matlab from a text file that has roughly 800k lines,  and looks like this:

```
"209","1000",".10500","N/A","36","116","2006-03-16 00:00:00","2519","431.400000","-6.760000","568.600000","142.620000",".000000",".000000",".000000",".000000","2","CHARGEOFF","","","2008-02-16 00:00:00","33.100000"
"190","1000",".18750","N/A","36","116","2006-03-14 00:00:00","0",".000000","-5.230000","1000.000000","269.370000","20.000000","60.000000","4.910000",".000000","4","COMPLETED","","","2009-03-14 00:00:00",".000000"
```

but, for some entries (which are not shown above) a comma is part of the string inside the quotes. For example, "N,A".

To simplify, I sed'd all " out of the file, then I was left with uneven number of commas for some lines and importing data into Matlab became even more difficult.

readtable can import this, but it takes too long and values are then stored as characters, for example instead of storing 209 as number it would import it as a string with contents '209'

Thanks!

Comment: I would also suggest you to try python. In practice, I have seen it to be very fast at reading text files.

Answer (score 0):

First I save the following string in the file `yourFile.txt`. Note the `,` between `N` and `A`

```
"209","1000",".10500","N,A","36","116","2006-03-16 00:00:00","2519","431.400000","-6.760000","568.600000","142.620000",".000000",".000000",".000000",".000000","2","CHARGEOFF","","","2008-02-16 00:00:00","33.100000"
```

I first use [`readtext`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10946-readtext) to read the text file as follows:

```
fileContents=readtext('yourFile.txt',',"'); %      ," is the delimiter.
% If you want to keep the entries between the quotes as characters.
processedContentChar=cellfun(@(x) regexprep(x,'"',''),fileContents,'uni',0);
% If you want numeric entries, however 'N,A' will be converted to NaN.
processedContentNum=cellfun(@(x) str2double(regexprep(x,'"','')),fileContents,'uni',0);
```

Comment: Yes thank you this works. On 330k lines with 22 columns readtext command takes 417 seconds. Then processing is relatively quick at 153 seconds.

Comment: The main file is roughly 800k lines with 420 columns, I will try it for timing, but I think it will be too long

Comment: How much time does `readtable` take in comparison? Also, I think you can write your own `textscan` command to read the file. I just used `readtext` because it was convenient.

Comment: On 330k lines readtable takes 6 seconds. On 800k lines with 420 columns some powerful computers need to be used and it takes maybe 20 minutes. Textscan would be too slow for this. I think fscanf would be fastest and I am trying to figure out the format spec for the file and it probably needs pre cleaning with sed first

Answer (score 0):

what I did was prep the data using sed to find |, remove them, replace "," with | and then find " and remove them. Basically using the idea of the answer above from Parag.

```
    time sed 's/|//g' file.csv | sed 's/","/|/g' | sed 's/"//g' > file_bar.csv
```

That took 3.5 min on ~800k line file with 540 columns

Then in Matlab I used readtable specifying delimiter as | and that took 10 mins.